# PostgreSQL Query: How to get Group-By to Roll Up

Tags: postgresql, group-by

[image: excel doc showing desired query output]

Data:
There are 2 possible statuses, 0 or 1
There are a variety of different Sub Statuses and sources

I am looking to create a query that will accomplish the following:
By Week/Year, show the number of unique instances of each status, sub status and source combination. I do have UIDs I can count for "number of instances".

I have written the following:

```
SELECT date_part('week', date) as week, date_part('year', date) as year, active_date, status, sub_status, source, id
FROM public.users
WHERE status < 2
GROUP BY created_at, active_date, status, sub_status, source, id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Which accomplished the following:
[image]

How do I get these to roll up?

Thanks!

Comment: @Nicarus, thanks for the edit. Apologies for the miss on the code there.

Comment: The `id` column in your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` is impacting your result. When you remove it, does it give you the results you want? Or are you trying to perform and aggregation on the `id`, like `count(distinct id)`?

Comment: When I remove the id from group by and select, I get the same results with the furthest right column removed. I was hoping to see the count of unique IDs with each combo of status, sub status, and source.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the terms 'week' and 'year' are reserved words. by replacing them with 'theweek' and 'theyear', as well as adding in a count function, I was able to roll these up.

```
SELECT date_part('week', created_at) as theweek, date_part('year', created_at) as theyear, status, sub_status, source, Count(*)
FROM public.users
WHERE status < 2
GROUP BY theweek, theyear, status, sub_status, source
ORDER BY theweek DESC
```

Results looked like the following:

[image: results rolled up by week, year, status, sub-status, source]

Thanks everyone!